# How do I find the cause of crash from complicated crash log

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject, sigabrt, crash-log

Here is the crash log. From this what I understand there is a crash because of some null or array out of index thing.

Because the exception type is **EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)** and exception note is **EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY**

Other than that I don't understand anything from the crash log.

It says **NSObject+ 1048524 (NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]** and it doesn't mean anything to me. there are no other informaiton in crash log to say where exactly the crash happened and what line the error has occured. I have seen some crash logs that gives lots of information like which line the error has happened and what could be the cause but this one doesn't have anything.

```
Incident Identifier: DA8D4971-24BF-4865-87FD-93A2F2CCA1FD
CrashReporter Key:   503ddaac3c197c2ebb4a9e32e69d1746f02ca3dd
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,4
Process:             MyAPP_MyTesting_Environment [411]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7E041111-CAD9-4040-B3F4-7CADCCABE915/MyAPP_MyTesting_Environment.app/MyAPP_MyTesting_Environment
Identifier:          com.mycomp.internal.myapp
Version:             1 (4.5.6)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.mycomp.internal.myapp [422]


Date/Time:           2019-11-04 14:35:57.3458 +0000
Launch Time:         2019-11-04 14:35:26.0000 +0000
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                 0x1d67fb38 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib               0x1c907062 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                 0x1d684fcc -[NSObject+ 1048524 (NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 117
3   CoreFoundation                 0x1d6830be ___forwarding___ + 691
4   CoreFoundation                 0x1d5abdc4 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 19
5   MyAPP_MyTesting_Environment                 0x0012aa38 0xa9000 + 531000
6   libdispatch.dylib             0x1cd4d792 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 5
7   libdispatch.dylib             0x1cd4d77e _dispatch_client_callout + 17
8   libdispatch.dylib             0x1cd51d00 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 897
9   CoreFoundation                 0x1d63bd64 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 3
10  CoreFoundation                 0x1d639e14 __CFRunLoopRun + 843
11  CoreFoundation                 0x1d58d1aa CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 465
12  CoreFoundation                 0x1d58cfcc CFRunLoopRunInMode + 99
13  GraphicsServices               0x1ed37b3c GSEventRunModal + 75
14  UIKit                         0x22915a4e UIApplicationMain + 145
15  MyAPP_MyTesting_Environment                 0x00134740 0xa9000 + 571200
16  libdyld.dylib                 0x1cd7a4e6 _dyld_process_info_notify_release + 25


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1ce4dacc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x1cf06086 pthread_kill + 62
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x1cde295a abort + 108
3   libc++abi.dylib               0x1c8e7708 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib               0x1c8fe552 default_unexpected_handler+ 99666 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib               0x1c90731e _objc_terminate+ 29470 () + 234
6   MyAPP_MyTesting_Environment                 0x001b0d70 0xa9000 + 1080688
7   libc++abi.dylib               0x1c8fb98e std::__terminate(void (*)+ 88462 ()) + 78
8   libc++abi.dylib               0x1c8fb1a2 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func+ 86434 (_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
9   libobjc.A.dylib               0x1c907138 _objc_exception_destructor+ 28984 (void*) + 0
10  CoreFoundation                 0x1d684fd0 __methodDescriptionForSelector + 0
11  CoreFoundation                 0x1d6830c2 ___forwarding___ + 696
12  CoreFoundation                 0x1d5abdc8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
13  MyAPP_MyTesting_Environment                 0x0012aa3c 0xa9000 + 531004
14  libdispatch.dylib             0x1cd4d796 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
15  libdispatch.dylib             0x1cd4d782 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
16  libdispatch.dylib             0x1cd51d04 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 902
17  CoreFoundation                 0x1d63bd68 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
18  CoreFoundation                 0x1d639e18 __CFRunLoopRun + 848
19  CoreFoundation                 0x1d58d1ae CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
20  CoreFoundation                 0x1d58cfd0 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
21  GraphicsServices               0x1ed37b40 GSEventRunModal + 80
22  UIKit                         0x22915a52 UIApplicationMain + 150
23  MyAPP_MyTesting_Environment                 0x00134744 0xa9000 + 571204
24  libdyld.dylib                 0x1cd7a4ea start + 2
```

Any help to better understand the crash log is appreciated

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log

Comment: Naveen did you try to use breakpoints. Just put some breakpoints on same viewcontroller and go step by step to check where your app crashes.

Comment: Add exception breakpoint

Comment: It's not reproducible that's the problem. I'm supposed to understand this crash log and do some fix based on this

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log.   That will tell you where in your code contains the frame 6 and frame 13.   The underlying issue is that the code tried to call an unrecognized method on an object.  Most likely, you have a callback block that is getting passed an argument of an unexpected type (though there could easily be other issues in play).

Comment: Start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html